# Using a boolean attribute in Core Data Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I am new to core Data and I want to create a boolean atribute to my App. My entity is RemoveAds and the atribute is isAdRemoved. I want it to inicialize it to false if the ad was not removed yet, but when he press a button to remove the ad it turns into true, any suggestions?

Obs: I have all my IAP setup, this is not the issue here

Update 1:

```
func removeallAds() {

        var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
        var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("RemoveAds", inManagedObjectContext: context)

        let newObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context) as RemoveAds

            newObject.isAdRemoved = false

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Setting a boolean attribute? Did you try `object.isAdRemoved = true/false`? Or defining a default value for a boolean attribute in the Core Data model inspector? Or defining a button action? How is the problem related to IAP? – Currently it is unclear (to me) what you are asking for.

Comment: The problem is defining a default value for a boolean atribute in the Core Data and how to change it later

Comment: To change the value fetch the object you saved earlier using your core data context, change its attribute value in your code and then save again via the context.

Comment: please can you post the code as a answer as I said I am really new, and I have english issues too

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new object to CoreData, then you also initialize the attributes, e.g. to set your attribute default-wise to false use:

```
let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("RemoveAds", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

let newObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

newObject.setValue(false, forKey: "isAdRemoved")
```

Once you received a button press, search for the corresponding object and set its property to `true`, again with `setValue`.

There is also a some tutorials for CoreData and Swift e.g. [Your First Core Data App Using Swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift).

Comment: It displays Use of undeclared type RemoveAds

Comment: Check whether you import the class and/or if it is spelled correctly.

Comment: everything is correct, check the updated question to see the code

Comment: So you definitely have a statement `import RemoveAds`?

Comment: how should I import RemoveAds, it is not a framework

Comment: Sorry, that was  was a misunderstanding. I'm a bit unsure what is wrong, maybe it is the cast. You could try removing it and use `setValue:forKey:`. But IMO it could also be something in your class definition of `RemoveAds`. However, without any additional information it is not that easy to solve it. Maybe extend your original question with some (!) more code, e.g. the definition of `RemoveAds`.

Comment: RemoveAds is not a class is a core data Entity

Comment: Ah! Now, this is clear to me. I thought it is a class. Please see my updated answer then. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to save a global app preference? If so, NSUserDefaults is likely a far better choice than Core Data.

http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/quick-tips/storing-data-with-nsuserdefaults/ https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html

Comment: Ok, but suppose it is default true, but when you press a button it will turn it to false, when I reopen the app it will be true or false?

Comment: It will be what you set it to be. But if you have many ads, IMO it is preferable to use CoreData.